# How to push multiple JSON requests into an array using setState in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I have set the state called data and declared it as an empty array in the getInitialState(). Furthermore I have made an ajax call and acquired a JSON in return in the componentDidMount().

How do you push multiple JSON requests to the array called data using the setState method?

```
var Forecast = React.createClass({

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            data: [] 
        } 
    }, 

    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.serverRequest = $.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=3000,au&appid=005fa98ae858a29acf836ecdefac0411', function(result) {
            var tempData = result;
            this.setState({
                // Is there any way to push multiple JSON into an array? 
                // below line of code is my attempt
                data: tempData 
            });
        }.bind(this));
    }

     ...
}
```

Comment: `data[0]` is undefined, because the array is empty.. Don't know about the ajax call, are you sure the result is an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure jQuery doesn't auto convert to an array for you:

```
this.serverRequest = $.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=3000,au&appid=005fa98ae858a29acf836ecdefac0411', function(result) {
    var tempData = JSON.parse(result);
    this.setState({
        data: tempData // reset the data
    });
}.bind(this));
```

Something of that sort will work

EDIT: You aren't following the protocol of the API. I manually typed it into a browser, and got this result:

```
{"coord":{"lon":144.96,"lat":-37.81},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":283.48,"pressure":1032,"humidity":76,"temp_min":282.15,"temp_max":285.15},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":4.6,"deg":360},"clouds":{"all":75},"dt":1497828600,"sys":{"type":1,"id":8201,"message":0.0048,"country":"AU","sunrise":1497821707,"sunset":1497856068},"id":0,"name":"Melbourne","cod":200}
```

Which is clearly not an array (therefore you cannot say `data[0]`)

If you want to access the JSON object just go like:

`console.log(data["coord"]); // this will return {"lon":144.96,"lat":-37.81}`

EDIT: If you want to store a list of requests, you need to do this:

```
this.setState({
    data: this.state.data.concat(tempData)
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my code so that the state can accomodate an object. Is there any way to push an object into an array using the setState()? I'd like to keep the state as an array.

Comment: @Hooey okay, I see what you mean. Please add that to the question too

Comment: Thank you. I've just added to my question

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're getting the response from 'api.openweathermap.org' as a plain JavaScript object instead of an array. So you will have to change your initial state and `console.log` in `render` method accordingly.

```
getInitialState() {
    return {
        data: null
    } 
}

render() {
    console.log(this.state.data);
    //...
})
```

If you want to put your response into `data` array in the state, use `concat`.

```
this.setState({
  data: this.state.data.concat([tempData])
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you would like to put the returned object into the array, add it?

What about this:

```
...
this.setState({
  data: this.state.data.concat(tempData)
});
```

You could also push it to the `state.data` array, but then one more step is required:

```
this.state.data.push(tempData);
this.setState({
  data: this.state.data
});
```

And it would mean, to modify the state, which is not a good practice. For that example it might be ok, but it's not a good habit.

Comment: yes. It is not an array but a json object. I have a state that is an array. My aim is to put the object in the array using setState() as defined above in my code.